# How can I be sure myADT Bundle does not need update?

Tags: android

How can I be sure my ADT Bundle does not need update? Do I periodically check for updates or what? Whenever I do Check for Updates it says no updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for your current ADT version, if you go to `Eclipse > About Eclipse` and click on the ADT icon to find out what version of the ADT you currently have:

[image]

Now just check [this site](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) to find out, if it's the newest version.

Btw the ADT does not get updated so frequently, so I would recommend you to enable automatic updates, so you don't have to check for it manually. Go to `Eclipse > Preferences > Install/Update > Automatic Updates`:

[image]